# Why Isn't Postgres Using My Functional Index?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have a public copy of the Stack Overflow database here on AWS Aurora Postgres 15.5:

- Server: query.smartpostgres.com
- Username: readonly
- Password: 511e0479-4d35-49ab-98b1-c3a9d69796f4

The users table has this index:

```
create index users_length_displayname on users(length(displayname));
```

But when I run either of these queries:

```
select * from users where length(displayname) > 35;
select length(displayname) from users where length(displayname) > 35;
```

They don't use the functional index, as evidenced by [their query plans](https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/bf241298bge5f247):

[image: Query plan showing table scan]

So, uh, why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is a statistics/estimation issue.

I initially thought it might also be a datatype casting issue, since the column is `character varying(40)` and the index is using `text` but now realise Postgres is converting those for us.

I did manage to get it to use the index (in a bitmap scan) for the following different-but-still-awfully-estimated exact match query:

```
explain select * from users where (length(displayname)) = 35;
```

This proves it can use the index when the estimates are better, even if they're still way off.

If you run the following, does it use the index?

```
analyze users;
explain select * from users where (length(displayname)) > 35;
```

I couldn't verify this, as the user is read-only and therefore can't run `analyze`.

Comment: Great work! It was just the analyze issue - after running analyze, it works perfectly.

Comment: Nice, thanks, I realised that after posting and was trying to get an edit in before you noticed :)

Comment: An index on an expression makes PostgreSQL collect statistics for the indexed expression, but `CREATE INDEX` doesn't trigger an autoanalyze run, so you have to do it yourself.